# How to initialize an object using the assignment = operator?

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading

I am writing a class similar to as follows:

```
class FakeVector
{
private:
    int* contents = new int[4];
public:
    FakeVector()
    {
        // constructor code here.
    }
};
```

I want to initialize the class so that that the contents array is filled (similar to how the vector class is initialized) like this:

```
Fakevector fakevect {1,2,3,4}; // should result in contents = {1,2,3,4}
```

How do I do this? Do I have to overload the assignment operator or the constructor somehow?

Comment: You can't initialise with the assignment operator by definition - you can only assign to something that already exists.

Comment: You could write the constructor to take an [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).